# How many undead of each type can you control at one time?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, wizard, undead

With a 20 wizard necromancer, all magic items allowed (with the exception of sentient items) with the three attuned as usual, by RAW:

How many undead can you maintain control over with a 100% success rate at the same time? I want to exclude Finger of Death, and undead created by your own undead — just direct ownership.

I'd like to know how many of each tier of undead I can control. So from highest power to lowest power undead, in terms of CR, how many of each can I control? For example: mummies before ghasts, before ghouls, before zombies, etc. Meaning, if you could control 2 mummies or 4 zombies, take the mummies first, then move down spell slots.

Comment: Do you care about duration of control?

Comment: @PremierBromanov permanent. At no point can you lose control

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming here that your DM does not allow you to "cheat" by taking long rests more than once every 24 hours.

Your magic items are a Tome of the Stilled Tongue and 2 × Pearls of Power.

Every day, you have the following spell slots you can use to make or control undead:

9th level: 1 + 1 from Arcane Recovery + 1 from Tome of the Stilled Tongue = 3

8th level: 1

7th level: 2

6th level: 2

5th level: 3

4th level: 3

3rd level: 3 + 1 from Signature Spell + 2 from Pearls of Power = 6

#### Day 1:

- 3 × 9th level Create Undead = 6 mummies
- 1 × 8th level Create Undead = 2 wights
- 2 × 7th level Create Undead = 8 ghouls
- 2 × 6th level Create Undead = 6 ghouls
- 3 × 5th level Animate Dead = 18 skeletons
- 3 × 4th level Animate Dead = 12 skeletons
- 6 × 3rd level Animate Dead = 12 skeletons

**Total**: 6 mummies, 2 wights, 14 ghouls, 42 skeletons

#### Day 2:

- 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th level spell slots are used to reassert control over mummies, wights, and ghouls
- 6 × 3rd level spell slots and 3 × 4th level spell slots are used to reassert control over 42 skeletons
- 3 × 5th level spell slots are used to animate 24 skeletons

**Total:** 4 mummies, 2 wights, 14 ghouls, 66 skeletons

#### Day 3 and onwards:

- 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th level spell slots are used to reassert control over mummies, wights, and ghouls
- 6 × 3rd level spell slots, 3 × 4th level spell slots, and 3 × 5th level spell slots are used to reassert control over 66 skeletons

**Total:** 4 mummies, 2 wights, 14 ghouls, 66 skeletons

Comment: jeezus finally. you are my hero mini. Thanks for the work you put into this!

Comment: What about the necromancer's 14th level feature? Command undead on a Mummy Lord? They have an 11 Int so as long as they fail the save, that would be considered permanent control if you didn't use the feature again. You'd just have to find one.

Comment: @FREE99 I specifically excluded this through the use of my "100% success" and that would be a quest all its own, honestly

Comment: This is slightly off, because he says the wizard gets a 9th level slot for Arcane Recovery, but Arcane Recovery gives you spell slot levels equal to half your character levels, but none can be 6th or higher.  So a 20th necromancer could get two 5th level slots for Arcane Recovery at the highest.

Comment: @PhilBoncer You're right, I missed that. So there should be one less 9th-level slot and two more 5th-level slots. I'll fix it up when I have time.

Comment: The wights can each control 12 zombies if they kill using Life Drain. If **PC** controlling **A**, which controls **B** counts as **PC** controlling **B**, that's another 24 that can be added to the list. Swapping out the mummies for more wights would get you even more zombies in the chain, though that does require ignoring the requirement to take higher-grade undead if possible.

Comment: @Pilchard123 "I want to exclude Finger of Death, **and undead created by your own undead**"

Comment: Huh. So it does say that. Never mind then.

Answer (score -2):

Well, it depends on the spells you used and the kind of undead, but if we're talking about the structure you're specifying... rather infinite? The given the casting time on create undead is 1 minute, and targets 3 corpses to reanimate/control for 24 hours with complete success and that you have, at the 20th level, then six mummies, six wights and forty-two ghouls for a human necromancer with an 8-hour long rest over the course of a day. For an elf? Twelve mummies, Twelve wights and eighty-four ghouls over the course of a day, because of the shorter long rest (thanks, trance). But that's just create undead, alone. For animate dead you target a extra creature thanks to **Undead Thralls**, your 6th level Arcane Tradition feature. Plus you can regain three 5th level slots and one 4th level slot on a short rest once, and regain that on a long rest. Given the knowledge that a short rest is 1 hour and a long rest is 4 hours for an elf and 8 hours for everyone else, as an elf you could raise 210 zombies in a single day. That's 76,650 zombies made in a year. A plenty large enough army to conquer a small country. Nevermind [link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40981/how-to-raise-the-largest-possible-zombie-undead-army?rq=1) because that's just crazy and your DM will send all sorts of Paladin Heroes with minmaxed stats after you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39207/discussion-on-answer-by-axios-verum-how-many-undead-of-each-type-can-you-control).

Answer (score -3):

Honestly you can get well into the 100s if you cheese with wights since they can control undead. If you use all other spell slots on animate dead that is.

Comment: I think I would have a way easier time understanding your answer if you spent more words on explaining how you're strategy works. Show how you are getting wights, show that they control undead, and show how many undead this would allow you to control total. Also note that the question excludes "undead created by your own undead" so I'm not sure your method is even valid.

Comment: Oh and, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: This indeed doesn't seem to be a solution in the context of the question: “I want to exclude Finger of Death, and undead created by your own undead — just direct ownership.”

Comment: @doppelgreener was just about to mention this, thank you kindly